# XSL sequence in param

Tags: xslt, sequence, param

I found a way to pass a sequence of values between templates using the following code:

```
<xsl:call-template name="myTemplate">
    <xsl:with-param name="myParam" select="@foo, @bar"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

So, in this case the param `myParam` in the template `myTemplate` will be a sequence containing 2 values.

But, if you use the following code, it's not working:

```
<xsl:call-template name="myTemplate">
    <xsl:with-param name="myParam">
        <xsl:value-of select="@foo, @bar"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The result is a simple concatenation of `@foo` and `@bar`.
I also tried with `<xsl:copy-of select="@foo, @bar"/>` but it's the same result.

So, can someone explains me how to pass a sequence of values in the content of `<xsl:with-param />` and not directly via the `select` attribute.

Thank you.

Comment: What you call "list" is actually a "sequence".

Comment: Yep, edited. Thanks

Comment: So Is your question not answered?

Comment: `<xsl:copy-of select="@foo, @bar"/>` should give an error when used inside of the `<xsl:with-param name="myParam">`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Now, yes. So, we are agreed that I have to use `<xsl:sequence select="(@foo, @bar")/>` ? Because it still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can someone explains me how to pass a list of values in the content of
>   `<xsl:with-param />` and not directly via the `select` attribute.

Not sure why it's necessary to avoid the `select` attribute. In fact, I believe it's preferable.

But to answer your question, you can use [`xsl:sequence`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-sequence).

---

This is, of course, all in the context of XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that `xsl:sequence` alone does not work, you need an `as` attribute on the `with-param` as well: `<xsl:with-param name="myParam" as="attribute()*"><xsl:sequence select="@foo, @bar"/></xsl:with-param>`.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, yep now it works well. Thank you to you guys.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, to anwser at your remark, I avoid the `select` attribute because I have to use a `<xsl:choose />` with multiple `<xsl:when />` to determine my value.

Comment: @dgedge03 I don't see what difference it makes. IMHO, adding the `as` attribute to the `xsl:with-param` instruction results in exactly the same sequence as the one produced by `<xsl:with-param name="myParam" select="@foo, @bar"/>`.  So this is just a roundabout trip to end in the same place.

Comment: @dgedge03, note that XSLT/XPath 2.0 has an `if (exp) then ... else` conditional expression you can use instead of `xsl:choose/xsl:when`, e.g. `<xsl:with-param name="param-name" select="if (condition) then (@foo, @bar) else if (condition2) then @foo else @bar"/>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k 1st point: yes IMHO too, but if I omit it it doesn't work. 2nd point: yes I know it, but I think it is more readable

Comment: I think it would be best if you expanded the question (or preferably post a new one) and explain the *real* problem. Right now, this has all the makings of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).